# Finding membership in Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a Python dictionary as below:

```
d={ 'cs101': {'name': 'Building a Search Engine', 'teacher': 'Dave',
    'assistant': 'Peter C.'},
    'cs373': {'name': 'Programming a Robotic Car', 'teacher': 'Sebastian',
    'assistant': 'Andy'}
}
```

I need to find if the name 'Peter' is a teacher or assistant for any of these elements. Note that 'Peter' and 'Peter C.' are two different persons. Suppose `coursename` is a variable to loop through `'cs101'` and `'cs373'`. If I use 'in' keyword to check membership:

```
'Peter' in d[coursename]['assistant']
```

it will return True.

Similarly, `'' in d[coursename]['assistant']` will also return True.

So, it seems that I cannot use the `in` keyword..

Can someone tell me how to check the membership?

Comment: why would you test if '' is in a string?

Comment: I know, it should be == ,my mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Peter, where art thou?

`'Peter' in 'Peter Pan'` will check if the string *'Peter'* can be found somewhere in *'Peter Pan'*, which is obviously true.

If you want an exact match you should use `==`, as in the below example:

```
'Peter' == d[coursename]['assistant']
```

<sup>The above will do a *case-sensitive* match, if you'd like to do it *case-insensitive* you could write: `'Peter'.lower() == d[coursename]['assistant'].lower()`.</sup>

---

#### Some examples of the differences between `in` and `==`

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 13 2012, 00:05:08) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> 'Peter' in 'Peter Pan'
True

>>> 'Peter' in 'Prince Pan'
False

>>> 'Peter' == 'Peter'
True

>>> 'Peter' == 'Prince'
False

>>> '' in 'Bananas'
True

>>> '' == 'Bananas'
False
```

Comment: If you wanted to be able to be whitespace insensitive: `d[coursename]['assistant'].strip() == 'peter'` -- or case insensitive: `d[coursename]['assistant'].lower() == 'peter'`

Comment: @mgilson `d[coursename]['assistant'].strip()` is not whitespace insensitive, it only strips the left and right whitespace. To remove all whitespace you need: `d[coursename]['assistant'].replace(' ', '')`

Comment: @jamylak -- actually you'd need to replace tabs and newlines too ;) (Do I hear a regex calling?).  You're right though.  I was merely talking about this specific case where we're looking for `"Peter"`.  If you're comparing against the literal `"Peter"`, `strip()` is good enough.

Comment: @mgilson right my bad, well then it would be something like `''.join(d[coursename]['assistant'].split())`. Don't need regex!

Comment: @jamylak -- or `d[coursename]['assistant'].lower().split() == name.lower().split()` *case and whitespace insensitive*  (No need to join, who knows if there were extra spaces on the RHS?) We might be on to something here!

Comment: @mgilson Hmmn I guess so although it looks a bit crazy :D Actually I got used to it now. :)

Answer (score 1):

Check specifically if the strings are equal rather than using `in`

```
'Peter' == d[coursename]['assistant']
```

will only be true when the string is exactly 'Peter'

Answer (score 0):

Something like this depending on what exactly you want to do since it is a bit unclear:

```
'Peter' in (d[coursename]['teacher'], d[coursename]['assistant'])
```

This checks if `'Peter'` is equal to one of the values in the tuple unlike your test where you check if `'Peter'` is in a string.

Answer (score 0):

For this you will have to use a loop if you have multiple keys (Python 3.9). Won't be possible with a one-liner until and unless you're using another module which allows that.

```
for k in d.keys():
    if 'Peter' in d[k]['assistant']:
        print(True)
```